# Youtube - "YT" not defined

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to use the youtube player via this code:

```
        var tag = document.createElement('script');

        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

            new window.YT.Player("video", {
                height: '432',
                width: '768',
                videoId: link,
                playerVars: {
                    'playsinline': 1, 'autoplay': 1
                },
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }
```

However, keep getting an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Player' of undefined

Comment: you need to wait for the script to finish loading before using a variable it defines - use `tag.onload` or `tag.addEventListener('load', .....)` and put that code in there

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines from the code:

```
events: {'onReady': onPlayerReady,
'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
}
```

**OR**
Add the function `onPlayerReady()` and 
`onPlayerStateChange()`

**Try it somewhere else as Stack Overflow is facing trouble playing it**:

```js
var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: '668nUCeBHyY',
          playerVars: {
            'playsinline': 1
          },
        });
      }
```

```html
<div id="player"></div>
```